# What was the correct action for this post in first post queue?

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24700650/xml-transformation-using-xsl-by-saxon-in-sun-os

I thought about flagging it because something seems amiss about posting the email address in the question; however, I double checked the rules and saw nothing against it, granted it was a very brief check. It is clearly a poor question with not enough information; however, I wasn't sure if I should flag it (for moderator attention due to the email or just flag as a poor question), comment on it or some other action. Ultimately I just skipped it as I felt uncomfortable dealing with; however, I'd like to know how was I suppose to deal with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including the email can be removed, if for no other reason than that it's noise, as it's not relevant to asking the question.

The fact that the question doesn't contain enough information to be answerable means that it should be closed.  "Unclear" is generally correct for a post lacking sufficient information.